# Is there a CRM like tool for managing offline social personal (non-business) use?

Tags: webapp-rec, crm

Lately I found the need to more and more to take notes of my offline social interaction so I can go through them later. People's name, their child, what they do, hobby, etc. Just like CRM in business. Are there any webapps + iphone app that can help me with this?

Comment: Saw Bento before it looks to me more like a modern simplistic Ms Access. I think it could work, but I kinda wish something smarter that integrates with social networking sites when possible. But thanks for reminding me about Bento. Will give it another shot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems so far the closest fit that I could find on a Personal Relationship Management is Nibble http://www.nimble.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sugar CRM is a free CRM but you'll need to set up and apache server with php and mysql. You also have mobile apps for it. Check it out, it may be what you're looking for.

http://www.sugarcrm.com